# imageresizing.net plugin to allow image resizing/scaling/cropping

Tags: imageresizer

Is there a simple (jquery) imageresizing.net plugin that would allow me to easily integrate image resizing/scaling/cropping in my asp.net webforms application?

Answer (score 0):

Cropping, yes; [jCrop does this easily](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2011/combining-jcrop-and-server-side-image-resizing). There is also [a crop preview plugin we created for jCrop](https://github.com/imazen/studiojs/blob/master/jquery.jcrop.preview.js).

[StudioJS](https://github.com/imazen/studiojs) is a more complex plugin that tries to do everything (filtering, rotation, etc), but is slightly less refined overall.